# python - non-abstract method calls abstract methods

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have an example below:

The first script where I define the abstract class:

```
# test.py

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class A:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.x = a
        self.y = 0

    @abstractmethod
    def __foo_1(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def __foo_2(self):
        pass

    # that is what i'm wondering if it could be possible
    def run(self):
        self.__foo_1()
        self.__foo_2()
```

And the second script where I implement the abstract methods:

```
# test2.py

from test import A


class B(A):
    def __foo_1(self):
        self.y += 1

    def __foo_2(self):
        self.y += 2
```

Since i know for sure that `__foo_1` and  `__foo_2` must be called in that order, i want to write the non-abstract method `run` to do that (like in `test.py`). But it doesn't seem to work:

```
b = B(1)
b.run()

>> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods _A__foo_1, _A__foo_2
```

Is there anyway to do that? Since i don't want to rewrite the same `run`-method each time.

Thank you.

Comment: Your abstract method names are mangled with those leading underscores `__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that double_underscore attributes are somewhat magic in Python.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

So instead of overriding `__foo_1`, you end up with an abstract `_A__foo_1()` and an implemented `_B__foo_1()`

Comment: yeah i just realized it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... i found what i need, i just need to change the protected methods `__foo` to normal method `foo` and it all works.

Comment: the double-leading underscore` naming convention is for "private" methods and, as explained by JETM, triggers a name-mangling mechanism. The naming convention for "protected" methods is a _single_ leading underscore, so if you don't want to expose your "foo_x" methods just name them "_foo_x".